# EigenVector, Eigenvalues, System of ODEs, and Solution Verifaction

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, generalized-eigenvector

$\newcommand{\align}[1]{\begin{align} #1 \end{align}} \newcommand{\diffx}{\frac{dx}{dt}} \newcommand{\diffy}{\frac{dy}{dt}}\newcommand{\equation}[1]{\begin{equation} #1 \end{equation}}$

I am given  the following system of differential equations:$\align{\diffx&=2x+3y-7\\ \diffy&=-x-2y+6}$ .

My first step was then to write the equation into the following matrix format. $\mathbf{X'}=\pmatrix{2&3\\-1&-2}\mathbf{X}+\pmatrix{7 \\ 6}$.

I then proceeded to identify my $\mathbf{A}$, from which I got the following: $\equation{\mathbf{A}=\pmatrix{2 &3\\ -1& -2}}$. From which I begin to do the following procedure, and this is where I begin to assume my error is. I do the indicated the step $\mathbf{A}-\lambda\mathbf{I}$

Here I get the following matrix $\equation{\pmatrix{2-\lambda &3 \\ -1 & -2-\lambda}}$. From there I calculate the determinant, and the following eigenvalues (or at least I think thats what they are called.

$\det(\mathbf{A}-\lambda\mathbf{I})=\lambda^2-1=>(\lambda-1)(\lambda+1)=0 \therefore \lambda=\pm1$

After arriving at these steps I substitute in the known values into the $\mathbf{A}-\lambda\mathbf{I}$ so for $\lambda=1$ i got the following matrix:<\p>

$$\equation{\pmatrix{1 & 3\\ -1 &-3}}$$

From here I set up my system of equations: $\align{k_1+3k_2&=0\\-k_1+-3k_2&=0}$

## My Question

Is my work right thus far, and also how do I get my eigenvector from these values and do it for the other eigenvalue?

Comment: Your eigenvalues are correct ....+1. For the eigenvector it's not a system you have two equations and two eigenvetors ..you calculate them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\lambda =1$ you have the matrix:
$$\pmatrix{1 & 3\\ -1 &-3}\pmatrix {v_1 \\v_2}=\pmatrix {0\\0}$$
You find the eigenvector for the eigenvalue $\lambda =1$
$$v_1+3v_2=0 \implies  v_1=-3v_2$$
You can choose for example:
$$ v=(v_1,v_2)=(-3v_2,v_2)=v_2(-3,1)$$
$$v=(-3,1)$$
Do the same for the other eigenvalue.
For $\lambda =-1$ you have the matrix:
$$\pmatrix{ 3& 3\\ -1 &-1}\pmatrix {w_1 \\w_2}=\pmatrix {0\\0}$$
$$w_1+w_2=0 \implies  w_1=-w_2$$
You can choose for example the eigenvector:
$$ w=(w_1,w_2)=(w_1,-w_1)=w_1(1,-1)$$
$$ w=(1,-1)$$

Comment: Yay i solved my first problem of this type, and got it right thanks +1

Comment: Thta's great good job.. @EnlightenedFunky

Answer (score 1):

If $k_2=1$, then $k_1=-3$, hence $\begin{bmatrix} -3 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector.

Similarly, if $\lambda_2 = -1$, then we have $3k_1+3k_2=0$, again, if $k_2=1$ then $k_1=-1$, hence $\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ is another eigenvector.

Comment: Is the vector $\pmatrix{3\\-1}$ a vector too? Or $\pmatrix{6\\-2}$

Comment: any non-zero multiples of an eigenvector is another eigenvector.